# Process Builder or Workflow Updating Addresses "Country" based on "state/province"

Tags: lightning, workflow, actionfunction

Does anyone have experience creating a workflow where if the "State/Province" is (ex. IN, VI, MT, etc.) to auto-fill the country? I'm trying to prevent inconsistancies with Country spelling or Users leaving it blank.

Does salesforce have an App to do this? Our previous database would auto configure country based on State/Zip.

Comment: Better you could enable state country picklist, which is a standard solution for this problem.

Comment: Thank you so much!